# How do I view all syslog entries

Tags: grep, syslog, more

How do I view all messages in the syslog?  I am looking for messages that my program is generating that I have tagged with `[pistreaming]` so I can find these messages usign `grep`

```
sudo more /var/log/syslog | grep -i pistreaming
```

and I get output like this:

```
Feb 23 19:31:49 opcrd logger: Starting pistreaming service...
Feb 23 19:31:52 opcrd [pistreaming] Initializing websockets server on port 8084
Feb 23 19:31:52 opcrd [pistreaming] Initializing HTTP server on port 8082
Feb 23 19:43:21 opcrd logger: Starting pistreaming service...
Feb 23 19:43:24 opcrd [pistreaming] Initializing websockets server on port 8084
Feb 23 19:43:24 opcrd [pistreaming] Initializing HTTP server on port 8082
Feb 23 19:43:24 opcrd [pistreaming] Initializing broadcast thread
Feb 23 19:43:24 opcrd [pistreaming] Starting recording
Feb 23 19:43:24 opcrd [pistreaming] Starting websockets thread
Feb 23 19:43:24 opcrd [pistreaming] Starting HTTP server thread
Feb 23 19:43:24 opcrd [pistreaming] Stopping recording
Feb 23 19:43:25 opcrd [pistreaming] Waiting for broadcast thread to finish
```

but, if I don't `grep`, these messages don't seem to show up in the log; what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

use sudo grep -i pistreaming /var/log/syslog.

This will display all the content of the file and pipeline will refine the output and will only display the line containing pistreaming.

Thanks @panki

Comment: Useless use of cat, simplifies to `sudo grep -i pistreaming /var/log/syslog`. It you want paged output, pipe to `more` afterwards.